# Create a Unique Object for Each customer

Tags: java

**This is a HW assignment**

DisplayMenu.java

Customer.java

Account.java

So the question asks to make a menu and create an account for customer with unique Id.Once we create a customer object we create an account object for this customer.I could alway's say Customer c1 =  new Customer() but this is manually as I cannot control the number of objects that will be created.

My Question is how can I create unique Objects of customer and account type when the option menu is a do while loop.

Can some one shed some light on this

```
import java.util.*;



public class UserController{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option;
        do {  
            option=0;
            System.out.println("Please Select from menu below");
            System.out.println("1.Create Personal Customer");
            System.out.println("2.Create Commericial Customer");
            System.out.println("3.Record Transaction");
            System.out.println("4.Make Withdrawl");   
            System.out.println("5.Display Customer");
            System.out.println("6.Display Customer Summary");
            System.out.println("7.Display Grand Summary");
            System.out.println("8.Exit");
            System.out.println("Please Enter a option");
            try{
                option=sn.nextInt();
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Please Enter a number");
                option = 9;
            }
            //      System.out.println(option+"value is");
            switch(option){
                case 1: System.out.println("Enter the name of the Customer");
                    String Cname = sn.nextLine();
                    personalCustomer p1 = new personalCustomer(Cname);
                    break;
                case 2:break;
                case 3:break;
                case 4:break;
                case 5:break;
                case 6:break;
                case 7:break;
                case 8:break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Option Please choose a valid option");
                    break;
            }
        } while (option!=8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put them in a `List<Customer>`.

Comment: I can't really tell with what exactly you're having issues, but if it's storing the objects, use a list or map...

Comment: Show your code and we can try to help.

Comment: Will I be able to create new objects with Link??Each Customer object then invokes a account object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try experimenting with a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

do {
    customers.add(new Customer(/* Possible args */));
} while (/* condition to keep making customers */);
```

And then you can access them using `List.get`:

```
customers.get(0);
customers.get(1);
/* etc */
```

or many of the options in the [`java.util.Collections` Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

You could also write your own to better understand how to dynamically store objects.  Here is a rudimentary example.

1. You store the objects in an Array: `T[] list`
2. You add them to the next available space which is tracked by an integer `int nextIndex` which starts at 0 and is incremented each time something is added.
3. When you add something you check if you have reached the current capacity of your storage list, if you have, create a newlist (`T[] newList`) of double the size of the old list, copy over the values, and then replace the old list with this new list.

`T` is a [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) used to generalize the input that will be given.

```
class AutoExpandingList<T> {
    T[] list;
    int nextIndex;
    public AutoExpandingList() {
        this.list = new T[10];
        this.nextIndex = 0;
    }
    public void add(T item) {
        if (nextIndex >= list.length) {
            expandList();
        }
        list[nextIndex] = item;
        nextIndex++;
    }
    public void expandList() {
        T[] newList = new T[list.length*2];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            newList[i] = list[i];
        }
        this.list = newList;
    }
    public T get(int index) {
        return list[index];
    }
    // You could implement other methods here:
    //     remove(int index)
    //     insert(int index, T item)
    //     sort()
    //     etc...
}
```

Which you could now use:

```
AutoExpandingList<Integer> numbers = new AutoExpandingList<Integer>();
numbers.add(1);
numbers.add(5);

AutoExpandingList<String> strings = new AutoExpandingList<String>();
strings.add("one");
strings.add("five");

AutoExpandingList<Customer> costumers = new AutoExpandingList<Costumer>();
costumers.add(new Customer(1));
costumers.add(new Customer(5));
```

For you provided code you would simply implement one of these dynamic storage methods, and then use it to store your customers:

```
public class UserController{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        // ...
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        do {
            // ...
            switch(option){
                case 1:
                    // ...
                    customers.add(new personalCustomer(Cname));
                    break;
                // ...
            }
        } while (option!=8);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

In response to your comment, I would recommend checking against the whole list

```
public Customer searchByName(List<Customer> list, String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if ( list.get(i).name.equals(name) ) {
            return list.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Loop through each `Customer`, check against each customers name, and then get the `Customer` info from the returned object.

Comment: @PraveenBanthia No problem, I made an updated edit to include some application to the code you provided.

Comment: @PraveenBanthia Also if this answered your question I would appreciate it if you accepted it.

Comment: how can I get customer information from his name any idea

Comment: Thanks a ton you helped me though this